# Complete list of defines for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012

Is there a list of all the predefined defines that Visual Studio declares for you when you compile a project?

Obviously DEBUG or RELEASE are quite obvious but is there other defines that get declared automatically, for example when creating a Console Application or a Window Application or if the resulting assembly will be a DLL or an exe file.

Is there a list that contains them all?

Answer (score 0):

It's  just a bunch of properties set up in .NET framework .target files. To figure what exactly you need - you could track down chain of called targets and see what exactly affect one or another output. 
And if you dig deeper - you will see that there is pretty big list and it also condition'ed - some properties defined if other properties set to specific value etc.
What exactly you want to do with such list ? Do you want it just for studying or you have concrete task?

Comment: Basically I wanted to know when my application was being compiled as a console application vs a windows application. I wondered if there was a define for that.

Comment: I think you can rely on $(OutputType):
$(OutputType)== 'exe' for console application
$(OutputType)== 'winexe' for windows application.

you can check Microsoft.Common.targets for more values (line ~171 and below)